# Error 331 sending SMS

Tags: sms, 2.3-gingerbread, htc-dream

An SMS failed to be sent and when I checked out the details the last line said "Error code 331".

What does this error mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 331 is an error that you would get back from the SMS gateway. It means: No network service is available.

If you continue to get that message, I suggest you call your carrier.

Comment: Actually I retried and it was sent successfully but I wanted to know the error meaning. How did you know the meaning of the error? Is there a list somewhere of all error codes ?

Comment: I google'd "SMS Error code 331" and found a site that had a listing of the SMS Gateway errors.